# Beautiful Soup, fetching table data from Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm following the book "Practical Web Scraping for Data Science Best Practices and examples with Python" by by Seppe vanden Broucke and Bart Baesens.

The next code is supposed to fetch Data from Wikipedia, a list of Game Of Thrones episodes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php' + \
'?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'
r = requests.get(url)
html_contents = r.text
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
# We'll use a list to store our episode list
episodes = []
ep_tables = html_soup.find_all('table', class_='wikiepisodetable')
for table in ep_tables:
    headers = []
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for header in table.find('tr').find_all('th'):
        headers.append(header.text)
        for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            values = []
            for col in row.find_all(['th','td']):
                values.append(col.text)
                if values:
                    episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
                                    range(len(values))}
                    episodes.append(episode_dict)
                    for episode in episodes:
                        print(episode)
```

But at running the code the next errors shows:

{'No.overall': '1'}

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-8-d2e64c7e0540> in <module>
     20                 if values:
     21                     episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
---> 22                                     range(len(values))}
     23                     episodes.append(episode_dict)
     24                     for episode in episodes:

<ipython-input-8-d2e64c7e0540> in <dictcomp>(.0)
     19                 values.append(col.text)
     20                 if values:
---> 21                     episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
     22                                     range(len(values))}
     23                     episodes.append(episode_dict)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could anyone tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the code, it's with the **indentation** of the code. The third `for` loop should be in parallel with the second and not inside the second `for` loop. This is how it's shown in the book.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php' + \
'?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'
r = requests.get(url)
html_contents = r.text
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
# We'll use a list to store our episode list
episodes = []
ep_tables = html_soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable')
for table in ep_tables:
    headers = []
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    # Start by fetching the header cells from the first row to determine
    # the field names
    for header in table.find('tr').find_all('th'):
        headers.append(header.text)
    # Then go through all the rows except the first one
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
        values = []
        # And get the column cells, the first one being inside a th-tag
        for col in row.find_all(['th','td']):
            values.append(col.text)
        if values:
            episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
        range(len(values))}
        episodes.append(episode_dict)
# Show the results
for episode in episodes:
 print(episode)
```

Comment: ahah. The initial code was not well copied. ok. :)

Comment: Awesome Ananth , You're correct , I'll be more careful with identation , I'm new with python and even the book says that identation is one of the most common mistakes for newcomers , This mistake helped me to double check identation before looking for other answers , but , I think this way I learned more , thanks for you help Ananth , and also @karlcow , both answers are helping me to calrify and understand better what happened

Answer (score 0):

Your trace is

```
{'No.overall': '1'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karl/code/deleteme/foo.py", line 20, in <module>
    episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
  File "/Users/karl/code/deleteme/foo.py", line 20, in <dictcomp>
    episode_dict = {headers[i]: values[i] for i in
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is probably too indented and a bit hard to read with the choice of variables. And it would be useful to know what you are trying to extract exactly. The list of episodes?
Since the book maybe the table structure has changed.

If yes, then each revelant episode title has this shape.

```
<td class="summary" style="text-align:left">"<a href="/wiki/Stormborn" title="Stormborn">Stormborn</a>"</td>
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'
r = requests.get(url)
html_contents = r.text
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
# We'll use a list to store our episode list
episodes = []
ep_tables = html_soup.find_all('table', class_='wikiepisodetable')
for table in ep_tables:
    headers = []
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for header in table.find('tr').find_all('th'):
        headers.append(header.text)
        for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            values = []
            for col in row.find_all('td', class_='summary'):
                print(col.text)
```

Comment: Thanks , very apreciated karlcow , I'll dig more in the class name for further exercises . Regarding what is tried to be extracted, the book claimed that the code , and I quote: "Let us now try to work out the following use case. You’ll note that our Game of
Thrones Wikipedia page has a number of well-maintained tables listing the episodeswith their directors, writers, air date, and number of viewers. Let’s try to fetch all of this
data" I see that your response efectively fetched the Episodes titles , I'll try to get all the data proposed by the book,

Comment: which kind of data structure are you trying to build?

Comment: Is a list , but as you mentioned , this was just a not well copied code. I usually type the code when I'm learning instead of just copy it , to understand better , and get familiar with syntaxis , this time , I'll not forget what a bad identation can result.